# Does there is a converse for this result, i.e., $Something$⇒ $p$ is a prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory

One of the known results in number theory is the following:

If $p$ is a prime and if $a$ is any integer, then $$a^{p}\equiv a\pmod{p}$$

My **question** is: Does there is a converse for this result, i.e., $Something$⇒ $p$ is a prime.

Comment: Well, if $a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$ for all $1 \leqslant a \leqslant p-1$, then $p$ is a prime.

Comment: However, beware of [strong pseudoprimes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_pseudoprime)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes; Fermat's Little Theorem essentially works because the multiplicative group mod $p$ is just a cyclic group of order $p-1$ - that is, it is isomorphic to the group of integers mod $p-1$ under *addition*. Moreover, since the order of the multiplicative group mod $n$ is always $\phi(n)$, where $\phi$ is the totient function, it holds that $n$ is prime if and only if the multiplicative group mod $n$ is isomorphic to the cyclic group of order $n-1$.

In practice, this amounts to saying that $n$ is prime if and only if there exists some $a$ such that $$a^{n-1}\equiv 1\pmod{n}$$
and that $n-1$ is the least positive exponent for which this holds - that is, for any lesser $0<i<n-1$, it holds that
$$a^{i}\not \equiv 1\pmod{n}.$$
The existence of a single such $a$ implies $n$ is prime.

Comment: @ Meelo: can you indicate a reference for that proof for inclusion in my work.

Comment: Well, [this](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-701-algebra-i-fall-2010/study-materials/MIT18_701F10_cyclic12.pdf) page gives a nice proof of the fact that such an $a$ must exist for any prime (i.e. that the multiplicative group mod $p$ is generated by a single element) - though it's a common theorem, so you could find it elsewhere. The converse, that such an $a$ existing implies $p$ prime is easy to prove - basically, my condition is "$a$ has order $n-1$ in the multiplicative group mod $p$", so the group's order is at least $n-1$, but if $\phi(n)\geq n-1$, then $n$ is trivially prime.

Comment: @  Meelo: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

[Wilson's Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WilsonsTheorem.html) is true iff $\;p\;$ is a prime:

$$1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot\ldots\cdot(p-1)=(p-1)!\equiv-1\pmod p\iff \;\;p\;\;\text{is a prime}$$